# How to align tables to top regardless if vertical or horizontally stack

Tags: css

Is it possible , regardless of the table height , to set width of #mytable , make #mytable table 50% , so you have 2 tables side by side stacked BUT have them all line up to the bottom of the one on top of it and not staggered because the table are different heights ? I cant change the HTML , so trying to do with css

```
<div id="mytable">
<table id="one"></table>
<table id="two"></table>
<table id="three"></table>
<table id="four"></table>
<table id="five"></table>
<table id="six"></table>
<table id="seven"></table>
<table id="eight"></table>
</div>
```

JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/BguL6/22/

in my fiddle you see the white gaps below the tables , possible to have them all aligned to top ? I tried veritical-align top but no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using CSS.

```
<div id="mytable">
        <div class="column">
            <table id="one"></table>
            <table id="three"></table>
            <table id="five"></table>
            <table id="seven"></table>
        </div>

        <div class="column">

            <table id="two"></table>

            <table id="four"></table>

            <table id="six"></table>

            <table id="eight"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
#mytable table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    #mytable #one {

        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }

    #mytable #two {

        height: 150px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    #mytable #three {

        height: 130px;
        background: green;
    }

    #mytable #four {

        height: 110px;
        background: orange;
    }

    #mytable #five {

        height: 90px;
        background: pink;
    }

    #mytable #six {

        height: 140px;
        background: purple;
    }

    #mytable #seven {

        height: 50px;
        background: blue;
    }

    #mytable #eight {

        height: 70px;
        background: white;
    }
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uSPsG/

Comment: Unfortunatly this won't work as per the OP. They can not change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with javascript using query and it requires tables to have absolute position, hope you will find it useful:

```
var yTable = [ 0, 0 ];
$('#mytable').children('table').each(function (k, v) {
    //calculate x of column + #mytable x
    var x = k % 2 * $(v).width() + $(this).offset().left;
    //calculate hight of column + #mytable y
    var y = yTable[ k % 2 ]+ $(this).offset().top;

    $(v).css({left: x, top: y});

    yTable[k % 2] += $(v).height();
});
```

JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/BguL6/23/